# Nreco.pdfgenerator throws Wkhtmltopdfexception with exit code 255

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, nreco

The above mentioned exception is thrown.

for particular sample html while for other records it works fine.
Html has link for css which if removed exception is not thrown.
But css is required.So need other solution.

Also : I checked for dependencies of visual c++ redistributable 2013.But seems that is not the problem.

Event log shows wkhtmltopdf crashed.

Comment: get the html and embed the css file content inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say anything concrete just by this information; if you're sure that problem is in the CSS, you can try to remove some rules to find which one causes wkhtmltopdf crush; for example, 'border-corner-radius' can be a reason in some cases.

Also I may recommend to run in command line wkhtmltopdf.exe for your HTML input that causes an error and see what is happening.